# What are peak times for Code Review answers?

Tags: discussion

This may be completely my perception (I'm admittedly working with a small sample), but it seems like a fair number of the answers on my questions here have come in the later afternoon and evening in the U.S. Does this reflect actual usage patterns?

Whether I'm correct about that or not, what are peak times for answers?

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/619483/distribution-of-user-activity-per-hour#graph), peak activity (counting questions, answers, and comments) is around 15:00 UTC.